# My courgette flower not blooming

Tags: vegetables

My courgette plants are growing well and started to have flower buds. However the buds did not bloom and instead the tips turn brown and they drop off.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Did you read the question @Graham suggested? Does that look like your problem, and does that answer help? If not, would you please add some more details to this question, especially pictures of your plants. Also, where do you live? Have these plants had healthy flowers and fruit before, but now they're not? Take a look at our [help]. In case it happens, [this page](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) explains duplicates. We hope you stay here and have fun!

Comment: @GrahamChiu This is different as the flowers are yet to open, whereas in your suggested post the flowers have already opened and fallen off.

Comment: In that case we need a picture